# How to cut extrude inwards like in sketchup?

Tags: mesh

In sketchup the extruding is similar to blender, but when I pull down it is different. I have a cube in sketchup and added 2 edges, and with the center face I pull down and it cuts to make the u shape.

**Sketchup**

[image]

I tried something similar in Blender, but it did not work.

After adding loop cut when pull down it created extra faces that I have delete and it adds more work to do.

Is there any method or how can i make a simple way cut or extrude downwards?

With the boolean can cut in sketchup, it's a simple way just to extrude downward and get what I want. Any suggestion or help which and make my work faster with this simple methods?

**Blender**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be my process of solving this:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Starting with blender version 2.9 there is a way to [Extrude Manifold](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/extrude_manifold.html?highlight=extrude%20manifold)
(<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>)

> This tool is very similar to Extrude Faces but enables Dissolve Orthogonal Edges by default. This causes the tool to automatically split and remove adjacent faces when extruding inwards.

[image]