# Architectural modeling and sketching directly in blender

Tags: modeling, workflow, tools

I used to make sketches directly in Sketchup desktop but now i'm moving to blender due to better *free freedom*.

BUT, the sketchup workflow is way more productive to start new model and change it than blender.

There is some set of commands and tools to mimic sketchup workflow productivty?

E.g.:

- create line and

  - snap to another edge
  - snap do mid point
  - "snap to edge normal"
  - when intersecting a edge, divide it edge in 2

(Maybe a opinion based question, but maybe there are some consolidated worlflows)

Comment: Have you done any research? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204457/what-free-tools-make-blender-work-like-sketchup https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78765/how-to-cut-extrude-inwards-like-in-sketchup https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16243/is-there-a-google-sketchup-mode https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67395/blender-equivalent-of-components-in-sketchup https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42710/translate-like-sketchup-move https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81715/mimic-navigation-in-sketchup-c4d

Comment: Thank you for the links, @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, but yes, I find some pontual needs like these, but not a compiled set of then.